# Issue with Enabling Keep Alive

Tags: keep-alive

I have used the following code to enable Keep Alive for my WordPress site in the htaccess file

```
# TN START ENABLE KEEP ALIVE
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>
# TN END ENABLE KEEP ALIVE
```

But still when I check my site performance in the GTmatrix site the recommendation is showing me to enable Keep Alive

I have even checked with my service provider they confirmed the Keep Alive is enabled in the Apache Configuration file

How can I enable Keep Alive, Can someone help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: You generally don't need to *enable* it, since it is the default behaviour for the http 1.1. The configuration you provided looks weird and is totally redundant.

Comment: Okay, but why does it shows enable Keep Alive when I test my site with GTMatrix, It shows my site needs Keep Alive to enable and a list of URL that serves

Comment: So, have you checked (manually, yourself) if it actually has keepalive or not? And without that header?

Comment: I have solved the issue, it seems like the test site is unable to retrieve the necessary information from the response headers but Keep Alive is enabled, thanks for your time

Comment: "it seems like the test site is unable to retrieve the necessary information from the response headers" --- that's a wrong assumption. I just checked one of my sites on the gtmatrix: 1) my site does not have the keepalive header 2) it serves keepalive connections 3) gtmatrix is happy. So, apparently you have not discovered the real problem. I would say if gtmatrix tells you the connections are not keepalive'd - there is no reason to not trust it.

Comment: So what else could be causing the problem and how can I solve this. I contacted my provider they said in their end it is enabled. They are not ready to give me instructions to access Apache Configuration file. I just followed the instructions from this site (http://softstribe.com/wordpress/how-to-enable-http-keep-alive-in-wordpress). If there is a plugin or other method to enable this would he helpful, Thanks

Comment: First would be to diagnose the problem. Have you confirmed yourself the connections are closed? Since it's not the best idea to fix the problem that you don't understand and/or cannot measure.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I fixed the problem

Comment: The explanation would be helpful for someone that comes after you.